# Sam left $30$ minutes later, his friends traveled $18~\text{km}/\text{h}$, Sam travelled $24~\text{km}/\text{h}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I'm having trouble with this question.

Sam had to leave $30$ minutes later than his friends. His friends travel at $18\text{km/h}$, and he travels at $24\text{km/h}$. How long before he catches up to his friends?

I think it's $24$ minutes by thinking logically, but I don't know how to put that in an equation. Please help! Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

After the first 30 minutes his friends will be 9km ahead of him

He then catches up with them at a rate of 24-18 = 6km/h (relative velocity)

9/6 = 3/2 = 1.5 hours

2 hours after his friends leave

Answer (score 0):

Hint: after $t$ hours, friends are at position $18t$, Sam is at position $24(t-0.5)$. When will they be at the same position?

Answer (score 0):

Since Sam's friends are traveling at a rate of $18~\text{km}/\text{h}$, they travel 
$$18~\frac{\text{km}}{\text{h}} \cdot 30~\text{min} \cdot \frac{1}{60}~\frac{\text{h}}{\text{min}} = 9~\text{km}$$
by the time he departs.

Let $t$ be the number of hours that have elapsed since Sam's departure. Then  at time $t$, he has traveled 
$$d = 24t~\text{km}$$
while his friends have traveled 
$$d = (18t + 9)~\text{km}$$
Since Sam catches up with his friends when he and his friends have traveled the same distance, we require that 
$$24t~\text{km} = (18t + 9)~\text{km}$$